# During testing, why is rails running my initializers twice?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, testing, initializer

I've created a brand new rails app, added a dummy controller, with an 'assert true' functional test, and an initializer that calls 'puts Rails.env'.

When I run rake test on this app, the initializer prints 'development' and 'test'.

Can anyone tell me why this is?

Peter.

Answer (score 1):

running rake boots up rails, then running your tests (test_helper, spec_helper) loads rails again for the testing environment

if you are using rspec you can invoke it without rake

```
bundle exec rspec spec
```

pretty sure with mini-test you can invoke using rake or ruby executable

there should not be any bad side effects running them via rake, just that you need to wait for rails to boot twice

Comment: The issue is that I have some code that needs to run in the development environment, but NOT in the test environment. The weird head-fake that rails does to always run the development environment means that there is no real way to achieve this. Is there a reason to boot rails in dev mode when running tests?

Comment: rake boots up in development mode - it should have no effect on your tests - those will run in a different process in test environment

Comment: That would be true except for the fact that the initializer in question populates the database. I want the population to happen for development, but not for testing.

Comment: but your tests don't run against the development database, they run against the test database - sounds like maybe you have something in initializers that belongs in a rake task instead? pre-loading data for development doesn't seem like something you want to do each time you restart rails?

Comment: I don't have the luxury of separate databases. I'm running against a legacy system through a (not-very) db-like api.